# External Data source definition Tomcat 7

Tags: java, jboss, tomcat7, datasource, jndi

Is it possible to define the **dataSource** configuration in a separate XML file other than **server.xml** and **context.xm**l in **Tomcat 7** as the case of **JBoss** where you can put the file "project_ds.xml" for example directly under the **deploy** folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example war file

```
sample.war
```

put it in an xml file called sample.xml with your datasource and whatever else in the directory

```
tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost
```

That sets specific settings just for that application.

Comment: Can you send me an example ?

Comment: just create that xml at that path and put your datasource definition within the tags <Context> INSERT HERE </Context>

Comment: also see the documentation at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context

Comment: Is it possible to define a datasource file in the /catalina /{host} folder with a different name than the war

Comment: yes. but it will only work for the war file the file is named after.

Comment: I didn't understand can you detail your answer. In my case I have two projects sample-1.war and sample-2.war. I want to put a single sample-1.xml file sharing between the two in the the /catalina /{host} folder